# Extract the second field of a pipe-delimited record

Tags: perl

I am using perl.

Here is the string which is $match_name:

```
|1015809840|ref|NG_009004.2|
|1015809841|ref|NG_009005.2|
```

I want the output to be:

```
1015809840
1015809841
```

I try:

```
$match_name =~ s/(.*?|.*?)|.*//g;
```

It removes all the characters.

Comment: `(.*?|.*?)` is rather pointless. inside `()`, `|` is "or", not a pipe character.

Comment: @MarcB Not just inside parens: `perl -E'say "foo" =~ /f|x/'`

Comment: s/^.*[I]([^|]+).*?$/$1/ ...another proposal ^^ removes any chars before the first pipe too.

Comment: Another possibility would be to split the line at the pipes and use the second entry of the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my ($second_field) = $row =~ /^ [^|]* \| ( [^|]* ) \|/x;
```

```
my $second_field = ( split(/\|/, $row) )[1];
```

Probably best to use [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS), though.

Comment: @ikegami $match_name =~  s/^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\K.*//s gives me: |1015809840| How to remove both '|'

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have fixed-width data. You can certainly use a regex to work with fixed-width data, but I prefer [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = unpack 'x A10 x A3 x A11';
    say $fields[0];
}

__DATA__
|1015809840|ref|NG_009004.2|
|1015809841|ref|NG_009005.2|
```

Output:

```
1015809840
1015809841
```

The `unpack` template `x A10 x A3 x A11` means:

- `x`: skip a character
- `A10`: read 10 characters into the first field
- `x`: skip a character
- `A3`: read 3 characters into the second field
- `x`: skip a character
- `A11`: read 11 characters into the third field

[perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) gives a great introduction to using `pack` and `unpack` with fixed-width data.